# C# Detecting server setup

Tags: c#, logging, settings, detect

I'm writing a program that deals with the logs generated by the clients server. How can I detect where the user is storing them? It feels invasive to search all files, but what if they're being stored outside of the root. Is this acceptable, what if I make the user click "detect" first? Regardless, what if they've been renamed and reformatted? Is it possible to read the server settings themselves from my external program? I want this to work on linux and windows servers. I need WC3 Extended format w/ several fields enabled that are not naturally. I also don't want it to return null if it's enabled but no log has been yet created. I don't want to force the user (assumed dumb) to play with settings.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hardcode where you expect them to be in the common case, and if they're not there, ask the user about it.  Doing more "magic" than that seems like a recipe for over-complexity and mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is specifying the location of the log file, then either you should have the user locate the file(s) themselves or keep track of these locations somewhere else when they are saved. You don't need to be doing a full (or large partial) drive search.